# Install of openresty : nginx.pid not found

Tags: nginx, openresty

I try to install OpenResty 1.13.6.1 under CentOS 7. When I try to run openresty I get this error:

> [root@flo ~]# openresty -s reload
>
> nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

When I look at my logs, I only have 2 files:

> [root@flo ~]# ll /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/
>
> total 8
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0  1 mars  12:24 access.log
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4875  1 mars  16:03 error.log

I do not see how to find a solution.

///////////////////UPDATE//////////////////

I try to do this to folow the instructions of this page : https://openresty.org/en/getting-started.html

> [root@flo ~]# PATH=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin:$PATH
>
> [root@flo ~]# export PATH
>
> [root@flo ~]# nginx -p `pwd`/ -c conf/nginx.conf

And I have this error :

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/root/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
>
> 2018/03/02 09:02:55 [emerg] 30824#0: open() "/root/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

/////////////////UPDATE2//////////////:

```
[root@nexus-chat1 ~]# cd /root/
[root@nexus-chat1 ~]# ll
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root 1512  1 mars  11:05 anaconda-ks.cfg
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   65  1 mars  11:36 openresty_compilation
```

Where do I need to create these folders ?

```
mkdir ~/work
cd ~/work
mkdir logs/ conf/
```

In `/usr/local/openresty/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely nginx cannot open a log file because folder doesn't exists or permission issue.

You can see the reason within error.log file

Comment: Did you prepare directory layout as described on this page? Post please output of `tree /root`?

Comment: Thanks I found my mistake : I do that `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

`openresty -s reload` is used to tell nginx to reload the currently running instance. That's why it's complaining about the missing pid file.

Anyway, that's not the correct way to start openresty. Have a look at https://openresty.org/en/getting-started.html for instructions on how to get started.